# How to add a property to ALL objects in an array (data) using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

**Background**:  I have an array in data() that gets populated with objects from the backend. If the GET request retrieves 6 objects those 6 objects will update in the array.

**Problem**: I already understand vm.$set is needed to add properties to an object. But how do add properties to all object in the array?

I want to change:

```
 data() {
    return {
      expenseButton: [{key:value},{key:value},{key:value}]
         };
  }
```

to

```
data() {
    return {
      expenseButton: [{key:value, key2:value2},{key:value, key2:value2},{key:value, key2:value2}]
         };
  }
```

**Failed attempt** which logs newValue as a property in the array instead of each object

```
  methods: {
    check() {
      this.$set(this.expenseButton, "newValue", this.expenseButton.newValue);
      console.log(this.expenseButton);
    }
  },
```

**UPDATE**
How to target all objects in an array via vm.$set so that all objects has a new property called "newValue"

```
 data() {
    return {
      expenseButton: [{key1:value1},{key2:value2},{key3:value3}]
         };
  }
```

TO

```
 data() {
    return {
      expenseButton: [{key1:value1,newValue: ''},{key2:value2, newValue: ''},{key3:value3, newValue: ''}]
         };
  }
```

Comment: Use splice on the array or modify the array then replace it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `this.$set` in a loop:

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: '#my-component',
  data() {
    return {
      expenseButton: [{ key: 0 }, { key: 1 }, { key: 2 }]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    check() {
      this.expenseButton.forEach((o, i) => {
        this.$set(this.expenseButton[i], "key2", i * 2);
      });
    }
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.21/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>

<template id="my-component">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="x in expenseButton" :key="x.key">
       {{x}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button @click="check">Update items</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Appreciate it man! I there a explicit reason to break it into a seperate component

Comment: No, that's just for the demo

Answer (score 5):

You can use `$set` on arrays by passing the index at which you wish to set a new value.

However, since you're adding a new property to each item in the array, you could just map over the array items, add the property and replace the data item altogether which would be far more efficient.

```js
check() {
  this.expenseButton = this.expenseButton.map((obj) => {
    obj.newValue = ''
    return obj
  })
}
```

To retain reactivity, you will need to invoke `$set` on each index with the corresponding key-value pair. See [@blex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62011499/2150268)'s answer for reference.

```js
check() {
  this.expenseButton.forEach((_, index) => {
    this.$set(this.expenseButton[index], 'newValue', '')
  })
}
```

If the above resolves your question, please accept @blex’s answer as your accepted solution.

Comment: Yes, but now, `key2` is not reactive. Changes to it won't be detected

Comment: That's correct, though that is not the intended question and the OP needs to evaluate and discover this for themselves.

Comment: @Cue. "newValue" is not intended to replace the value of "key2".  But it is intended to be a third key/value pair like this: {key:value, key2:value2, newValue: '  ' }.

Comment: @EddieWeldon sure, just replace `obj.key2` with `obj.newValue`.

Comment: @blex You are right it is not reactive.  I am trying to add "newValue" using vm.$set feature.

Comment: @Cue I am trying to keep the updated property reactive via  vm.$set.  If you check my failed attempt you will see what I am trying to do.  The main problem is targeting all objects in the array

Comment: @EddieWeldon you also stated you wanted to change `{key:value}` to `{key:value, key2:value2}`, which is where I've been misled.