# Prevent Default Scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, ecmascript-6, quasar-framework

I have a button with a click event that is managed by my asynchronous method getComponents, basically it shows a q-card with the data given by my API, the problem is when the card is shown, the page automatically scroll up and I don't want this behavior, I tried putting a .prevent in the event or preventDefault in the method and doesn't work, I use Quasar Framework.

How can I fix this?

[Button that display the card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWn37.png)

```
<template>
  <ul class="q-mt-lg text-center">
    <li v-for="button in buttons" :key="button.id" class="q-mr-md">
      <q-btn outline rounded color='blue-10' :label="button.name" @click="getComponents(button.id)"/>
    </li>
    <component-card v-if="!isButtonPressed" :cards-info="componentsInfo" :description-info="descriptionComponent"/>
  </ul>
</template>
```

Method:

```
async getComponents (categoryId) {
  this.componentsInfo = []
  this.isButtonPressed = true
  const PathCategory = `http://localhost:8000/api/v1.0/category/${categoryId}/`
  const PathProduct = 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1.0/product/'
  try {
    const responseCategory = await Axios.get(PathCategory)
    const responseProduct = await Axios.get(PathProduct)
    this.filterComponents(responseCategory.data, responseProduct.data)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
```

Comment: Maybe at some point there is not enough content to fill the entire height of your browser viewport? In this case, the browser has no choice but to go back up. If you want your scroll to remain in the same position, you would need to make sure that your container's `min-height` is equal to the `clientHeight` that was effective before clicking on the button

Comment: @blex Yes, the div parent that hold all the cards have a min-height of 70vh, it has an ample height and it still behaves the same way.

Comment: Then it's really hard to tell what's going on. You might want to create a demo reproducing the problem here ([How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Not including all your code, nor your Ajax requests. Just enough to reproduce. Something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62011499/1913729)